# Kohana database select, list of fields

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

In Kohana if I want to select fields 'id', and 'username' I do it this way:

```
$record = DB::select('id', 'username')
                    ->from('users')
                    ->where('id', '=', 1)
                    ->as_object()
                    ->execute();
```

But how to do it if the list of fields I need to select is in an array, like this:

```
$fields = array('id', 'username');
```

How to use DB::select in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `DB::select_array()`.

You can also use `$record = call_user_func_array('DB::select', $fields)` and then continue building the query; it might be ugly but it also works :)